# How to get index of parent of parent in YUP?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I have a YUP schema like below:

```
object({
  conditions: array(
    object({
      type: string(),
      id: string(),
      condition: array(
        object({
          value: string().test(
            "test-condition-name",
            "Condition name must not be empty",
            function (originalValue, context) {
              console.log("originalValue-->", originalValue);
              console.log("context-->", context);
              return errorTemplate(
                "validation_condition_node_value",
                "validation_condition_node_value_global",
                "asdasda"
              );
            }
          ),
        })
      ),
    })
  ),
});
```

What I need is I want to know id of conditions (first level array) while validating name of the condition (nested array).

How to access first level index here?